# How to open macOS news article in browser?

Tags: macos, mojave, apple-news

I like the Apple News app, but can't figure out how to open the articles in browsers (For sharing purposes).

The Share button doesn't have "open in browser" as an option.
I've tried sharing a note, but then it hides away the URL behind the apple news rich image.
I tried it in mail, but then it gives me the news URL: https://apple.news/AfSvL4zUURbOnHGot9Tx7bA 
Which can be shared, but isn't the same, and especially cross-platform is just kinda... inconsiderate?

[image]

I can do this in iOS which is nice... But I can't figure out how to do this in macOS. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: If you paste the link into a non-safari browser, it redirects to the original link (tested in Chrome). So you could either copy the redirected link or just send the apple news link and know that recipients will be able to get to the original link.

Comment: Hi @JBallin, I didn't realise that Chrome doesn't open the Apple News application and just opens the link in Chrome itself! That's a viable workaround for me, thank you very much! If you give that as the answer, I'll accept it. :D With regards to your initial comment, the more annoying factor is people who go "Apple News? Who uses that? Google News is much better"... >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is available on macOS, but is unintuitive. In the `News App`, open the `File` menu, and select `Open in Safari`.

> NOTE: This will in fact open the link in whatever your default browser is (eg. Chrome) although the menu title will continue to say "Open in Safari" regardless.

In order to add a keyboard shortcut for this, open `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts`

1. select App Shortcuts in the sidebar
2. tap the + button to add a shortcut
3. from the Application dropdown, select News.app
4. in Menu Title, enter: "Open in Safari" (no quotes)
5. in Keyboard Shortcut, enter the shortcut you desire (eg. cmd-O)

Comment: That’s exactly it! Thank you! Crazy how it has no OOTB shortcut option. And that it’s conpletely at odds with how the share button works in iOS. I’ll give you style points for including the method to add style points if I could!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Edit -> Copy Link` to get the URL of the news item that is visible. Shortcut is <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: As stated above, this then gives me the apple news link of: https://apple.news/A_VKzB_0XS4WAmxycK_Su4g which still isn't great. Is there a way to get the original link?

Answer (score 2):

If you paste the apple.news link into a non-Safari browser (i.e. Chrome), it will redirect to the original URL.

---

I like @mga's [suggestion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/346805/151404) for how to actually get the link:

> Use Edit -> Copy Link to get the URL of the news item that is visible. Shortcut is ⌥+⌘+C